# Create custom grok pattern to message filed in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am having a query related to grok processor. 
For example this is my message filed

```
{
"message":"agentId:agent003"
}
```

I want to Grok this and my output should me something like this

```
{
"message":"agentId:agent003",
"agentId":"agent003"
}
```

Could some one help me on this how to achieve this? If i am able to do it for one field i can manage for rest of my fields. Thanks in advance.

**This is the pipeline i have created in elasticsearch**

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/dissectpipeline
{
  "description" : "split message content",
  "processors": [
    {
      "dissect": {
      "field": "message",
      "pattern" : "%{apm_application_message.agentId}:%{apm_application_message.agentId}"
   }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Central management added filebeat module other config**

```
- pipeline:
    if: ctx.first_char == '{'
    name: '{< IngestPipeline "dissectpipeline" >}'
```

There is no error with my filebeat it's working fine but i am unable to find any field like apm_application_message.agentId in index.

How to make sure my pipeline working or not. Also if i am doing something wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grok I'd suggest using the [`dissect` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html#_indirect_field_notation) instead with, which is more intuitive and easier to use.

```
dissect {
  mapping => {
    "message" => "%{?agentId}:%{&agentId}"
  }
}
```

If you're using Filebeat, there is also the possibility to use the [`dissect` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/dissect.html):

```
processors:
  - dissect:
      tokenizer: "%{?agentId}:%{&agentId}"
      field: "message"
      target_prefix: ""
```

Comment: If i use this processor in pipeline it is working fine in kibana console. but my intention is to dissect it when shipping the data to elasticsearch using filebeat. Could you please let me know how to use this processor in filebeat.

Comment: Note : i am shipping the custom log data of java application from log files using ECS logging for java applications using filebeat

Comment: Ok, I thought you were using Logstash, please see my updated answer.

Comment: My filebeat.yml is auto generated in the sense i have configured everything in beats central management. In that case where can we add the processor?

Comment: You should know, though, that [Beats Central Management will be discontinued](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/how-central-managment-works.html) for a better solution coming up in 7.8.

Comment: Yes by using filebeat module in cental management, i have selected elasticsearch and specified the pipeline which i have created. Filebeat working fine but no trace of newly created field. Given all my workarounds above for your reference

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Just for your information, Elastic stack 7.8 just got out a few minutes ago and the "better solution" (aka Ingest Manager) is described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/ingest-manager.html

Comment: FYI Blog article about Ingest manager and Elastic agents: https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-elastic-agent-and-ingest-manager